# Jquery templates: How to access data object from array

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

This example does not work for me:

```
$.tmpl('<span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-icon-${data}">\
        ${data}</span>', \
        ["info", "delete"]\
)
```

since it will return nothing in place of ${data}. I also tried with ${item} which gave me same result.

What i want to achieve, is to insert the text "info" in the first generated span and "delete" in the next span.

As a workaround, i can pass in objects like so:

```
[{name: "info"}, {name: "delete"}]
```

and access them with `${name}` directly.

But how to i make it work without the workaround?? What is the correct syntax for getting element in aray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add one `$` sign before data.
Change `${data}` to `${$data}`

Try this:

```
$.tmpl('<span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-icon-${$data}">${$data}</span>', ["info", "delete"])
```

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/ythSP/